# How to stop cold air from coming into the house

Tags: doors, draft

I have a door similar to this, but it is an external door.  There is a lot of cold air coming in from the bottom of this door, and around the perimiter (betweent he door and the frame).

This is a rental house, so I don't want to spend too much fixing this forever, just enough for it to be effective.

How do I prevent cold air from coming into the house?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For the bottom, you need to install a (or replace the existing) door bottom (Yeah, someone was really inventive with that name).  The thing goes on the bottom of the door and will fill the gap there.

There are 2 general types, ones with vinyl fins ([like this](http://www.canadiantire.ca/AST/browse/6/Tools/HomeRepairMaintenance/WeatherStripping/PRDOVR~0642558P/Bottom+Door+U-shape,+White.jsp?locale=en)) or ones with short brushes ([like this](http://www.canadiantire.ca/AST/browse/6/Tools/HomeRepairMaintenance/WeatherStripping/PRDOVR~0642592P/Door+Bottom+with+Synthetic+Fibres,+White.jsp?locale=en)).  I personally find the latter work better, though if you have a large gap, the brush type may not be long enough to fill the gap fully, though a gap that large likely means your threshold is improperly sized.

Comment: The "door bottom" is sometimes referred to as a "door sweep."

Comment: And for the perimeter. Doors often warp some, so that the original weather stripping no longer makes contact everywhere. Or the rubber hardens, losing it's ability to even contact the door. In either case, adding cheap stick on foam weather stripping will stop drafts from the perimeter. At least for a few years until the foam breaks down. By then, you've probably moved.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a under the door dual draft stopper that slides under the door like this below. 
This may work as a temporary fix seeing as your in a rental

http://www.improvementscatalog.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/twin-draft-guard-26-23174-door-draft-stopper/10784?redirect=y

Comment: Those things are not appropriate for exterior doors.  They'll just get jammed on the threshold.

Answer (score 1):

For a temporary, low-cost, low-hassle solution, you could just put a towel down in front of the door to block the draft. That's what we always did in my house as a kid.

[image: towel in front of door]